# activity send data to fragment but what fragment received is null

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

There is an activity containing a Button and a LinerLayout which is the container of Fragment. The layout of Fragment only contains a TextView. I want to send a string to fragment from activity, but what fragment received is null. Why?

xml of Activity:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/load"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:text="load" />

    <!--the container of fragment-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

xml of Fragment:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Java code of Activity:

```
public class DynamicFragmentActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dynamic_fragment);

        findViewById(R.id.load).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //create fragment and set data
                MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("text", "demo");
                myFragment.setArguments(bundle);

                //commit
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, myFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Java code of Fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_text);

        //receive data
        String text = getArguments().getBundle("text")+"";
        textView.setText(text);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this , Hope it helps ...........

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment, container, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_text);

    //change getBundle() to getString() 
    String text = getArguments().getString("text")+"";
    textView.setText(text);

    return view;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot. That is a great help. And I just try to change getBundle() to get(), it is ok too.

Comment: Use getString() , so you  can get it  as String and set it in textView.setText(text); . Please accept the answer if it helps you , thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing now is get a Bundle called text and what you really want is get a string in the bundle:

```
Bundle arg = getArguments();
String txt = arg.getString("text");
```